# How do I determine if 2 types of data are meaningfully related?

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, categorical-data

I've been asked to see if there's a meaningful relationship in the 5yrs of data we have that is worth putting more research effort into. Particularly, does a relatively small investment in x (<1,000/yr) decrease impact of a much larger possible cost in y (>10,000/yr)?

We have 1,000s of entries. Some entries were invested in, others were not. Some resulting costs in the future were >10,000, and others were 0. There are many categories of investments and sometimes multiple ones were used.

We are most curious about 1 of the investment categories.

Besides directly calculating means, variances and correlation, what other statistics might be useful?

Are the statistics I mentioned even useful without transforming the data somehow like with logs?

We're interested in costs but I thought about also looking at the frequency of the investments and the frequency of the future costs. Good idea?

Am I even approaching this the right way?!??!

I don't need to go as far as modeling (that's for the future). I'm not strong with statistics. Appreciate the help.

Comment: It's hard to answer this or comment without more clearly defined terms. (1) When you say "investment in $x$", what precisely is $x$? (2) What is $y$? (3) What's an "entry?"(4) When you say you have 5 years of data, roughly what kind of data is it? You'll get more useful comments/answers if your question is both clear and concise (to the extent possible).

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your input. Sorry I can't be too specific. I tried to reword the problem in another post that is hopefully clearer. I can't say what x and y are exactly but I hope that doesn't prevent a general approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without further details it's hard to give a clear answer. And there's often not a 'right' way to do it anyway.

However, it sounds like what you may be interested in is whether investments at one time of less than \$1000 yield a cost savings of at least \$10,000 at some point in the future. If this is what you're going for then you can view the problem as count data and make a table that looks kind of like

`|                 | Low Savings | High Savings |
|-----------------|-------------|--------------|
| Low Investment  | a           | b            |
| High Investment | c           | d            |`

From this you can measure association using a $\chi^2$ or permutation test for instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This looks interesting. Should I be using the whole data set we have to do this test or should I be sampling from it? I have the same question about correlation...